# How to install bundler with the version written in "BUNDLED WITH" in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile.lock

I want to install *bundler* with a specific version written in `Gemfile.lock`. Do you know how to do it? I want to let ci like Jenkins automatically install *bundler* of  the version.

```
BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.5
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, Are you asking, for how to install bundler based on the specific versions of the gems installed?

Comment: AFAIK, bundler reads the gemfile and installs gems based on versions specified in lock file and what you are asking is bundler installs/upgrades itself based on version written in lock file...I doubt it.

Comment: Don't think you can do so. bundler helps you manages gemfiles and therefore you can't use it to manage itself. If you want to specify the version of it I think it would be better for you to run it as a script (if you host on your own server), if you are using heroku I don't think you can specify it. [Read More Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#why-can-t-the-bundler-version-be-configured)

Comment: My intention is to install a specific version of bundler. The version depends on Gemfile.lock file.

Answer (score 4):

You might try a bit of shell scripting: `gem install bundler -v $(tail -n1 Gemfile.lock)`

Comment: Not sure if the `BUNDLED WITH` can appear in other parts of `Gemfile.lock`, but this might be a more robust way: `grep -A 1 'BUNDLED WITH' Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1 | xargs`. Takes the "BUNDLED WITH" line and the line after it, takes the last line of those, then trims leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit late to the party, but bundler 2.3 does this for you by default. See https://bundler.io/blog/2022/01/23/bundler-v2-3.html.

Answer (score -2):

- https://makandracards.com/makandra/9741-run-specific-version-of-bundler

  `gem install bundler -v 1.0.10`

  `bundle _1.0.10_ install`

Works for me :)